# limiting a collection of objects to a unique set

Tags: php, activerecord, spl

Currently I have a PHP class called `Collection`.  It uses an array to hold set of unique objects.  They are unique, not in the sense that they have different memory addresses (though obviously they do), but in the sense that there are no *equivalent* objects in the set.

I've been reading about `SplObjectStorage` which has significant speed advantages over an array and might be easier to maintain than my `Collection` class. My problem is that `SplObjectStorage` does not concern itself with equivalency, only identity. For example:

```
class Foo {
  public $id;

  function __construct($int){
    $this->id=$int;
  }

  function equals(self $obj){
    return $this->id==$obj->id;
  }
}

$f1a = new Foo(1);
$f1b = new Foo(1);//equivalent to $f1a
$f2a = new Foo(2);
$f2b = $f2a; //identical to $f2a

$s=new SplObjectStorage;
$s->attach($f1a);
$s->attach($f1b);//attaches (I don't want this)
$s->attach($f2a);
$s->attach($f2b);//does not attach (I want this)

foreach($s as $o) echo $o->id; //1 1 2, but I wish it would be 1 2
```

So I've been thinking about how to subclass `SplObjectStorage` so its `attach()` would be restricted by object equivalency, but so far it involves setting the `$data` of the object to an "equivalency signature" which seems to require looping through the datastructure until I find (or not) a matching value.

e.g.:

```
class MyFooStorage extends SplObjectStorage {

  function attach(Foo $obj){
    $es=$obj->id;
    foreach($this as $o=>$data) {//this is the inefficient bit
      if($es==$data) return;
    }
    parent::attach($obj);
    $this[$obj]=$es;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: so basically you want a kind of singleton based on a unique ID. Maybe you should get a static variable with an array inside, and store your objetcs with ID as array key

Comment: @Tsadiq: That's essentially what I'm doing with my `Collection` class.  But given that SplObjectStorage has been shown to be much faster than an equivalent array, I'm trying to figure out how to leverage it. http://technosophos.com/content/set-objects-php-arrays-vs-splobjectstorage

Comment: so maybe you just need a comparison method in your Foo that returns ths ID and compare what ID your two objects have :)

Answer (score 3):

If the only thing that defines equality is relative to another object, then I am afraid that what you want is impossible. Think about it, there is no way to determine that an object is already included in the array unless I check every object, so I will have a complexity of O(n) no matter what.

However, if you make the equality absolute then this is possible. In order to do that, you will have to produce a hash value for each of the objects. Two objects will be equal if and only if their hashes are equal. Once you have that, then you can achieve O(1) with a HashMap.

Under the hoods, this is exactly what SplObjectStorage does, by taking the address of an object as its hash value.

Comment: if instanciating is based only on the unique ID, then you don't need no hash, just an id property or comparison method

Comment: @Tsadiq. You play with names. The "id property" will be the "hash value".